# How to get the latest row added via fetch api

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am trying to get the latest added record via fetch to display. On the page before a user is submitting information to the api that i want to fetch and display as a receipt on next page.

So my idea is that the easiest would be to fetch the latest row added and display information from that. How could i achieve this or is there another way i should do this.

So for example in this case i would like to target the latest row which is report_id: 3. The report_id is the auto incremented value that is unique.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const fakeUserId = 1;


    function fetchReport() {

      return fetch('http://localhost:8888/api/problems')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {

        console.log(data.data);


      })
    }

    fetchReport();
```

LOG OUTPUT

```
 "data": [
    {
    "report_id": 1,
    "user_id": 1,
    "name": "Name1",
    "phone": "123"
    },
    {
    "report_id": 2,
    "user_id": 2,
    "name": "Name2",
    "phone": "1234"
    },
    {
    "report_id": 3,
    "user_id": 3,
    "name": "Name3",
    "phone": "12345"
    }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You're looking for `Array.pop()`

(so long as you dont mind modifying the original `data.data`. Pop will remove it)

```js
var data = {
  "data": [{
      "report_id": 1,
      "user_id": 1,
      "name": "Name1",
      "phone": "123"
    },
    {
      "report_id": 2,
      "user_id": 2,
      "name": "Name2",
      "phone": "1234"
    },
    {
      "report_id": 3,
      "user_id": 3,
      "name": "Name3",
      "phone": "12345"
    }
  ]
}

var lastItem = data.data.pop()

console.log(lastItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "data" is in the aptly named `data.data`, which is an array. One way to access the last item in an array is to access it via `data.data[data.data.length-1]`